# Keras learning without giving data

Tags: keras

So I started to build a new Thread for the model.fit function. Here my problems begin:
Is it possible to learn without giving data
example code:

```python
def game(model, X, Y):
    pred = model.predict(X)[0]
    return np.mean(np.abs(Y-pred))


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40, input_shape=(2,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")


X = np.array([[3,6], [8,9], [4,5], [1,8], [20,15]])
Y = np.array([[10],[18],[10],[10], [36]])


for i in range(1,500):
    testData = np.array([[0 ,0]])
    loss     = game (model, X, Y)
    pred = model.predict(testData)[0][0]
    _y   = np.array([pred+loss]) 
    model.fit(testData, _y, batch_size=1)
```

Comment: Please make the question clearer, what do you mean learning without giving data?

Comment: Every time for fit use testData = np.array([[0 ,0]]) and calculate loss my self in game function

Comment: That would be more like reinforcement learning, you cannot compute the loss yourself because it needs to be symbolic in order to compute gradients.